# What is the difference between adding an exclusion by a file or application?

Tags: terminology, malwarebytes

In Malwarebytes there are several options for adding an exclusion. One is "Exclude a file or folder" another "Exclude an application that connects to the internet". What is the difference? An application is a file.

I'm asking what the difference is between the first and third option
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.malwarebytes.com/support/guides/mbam-legacy/MalwareExclusions.html) t for more details.

Comment: @vembutech that doesn't answer the question

Comment: File is for the malware scanner, application is for the (application) vulnerability feature. Malwarebytes 3 combined three of their programs into one.

Comment: @Ramhound that makes sense. So the difference is now obsolete? I was having trouble adding an exception but it seems to be solved by a reboot.

Comment: No; your using Malwarebytes 3, your question is relevant, just don't have a pc with it installed with it to take proper screenshots

Comment: @Ramhound I don't follow you. This is a screenshot of Malwarebytes 3 running on my PC.

Comment: TI just said you were, you asked, if it the difference was obsolete...the difference is the anti-malware vs anti-exploit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application is not considered just a file. All it's components are taken into account. An application can have a launcher, the main .exe file and several other secondary .exe files. Applications often use shared components or special runtime libraries. Blocking the application should take all this into consideration if the blocking tool is good. In the case of MWB, the application sub-components will be excluded even if any of them try to connect to the internet, not the main .exe itself.

Excluding an .exe file does just that, not considering anything else.
If that .exe uses a sub-module to do something, the sub-module will not be excluded.